# Does ExoPlayer support MP4 Playlist?

Tags: android, mp4, playlist, exoplayer

Does ExoPlayer support playlist as sourceData ?

I need to get an array of url's streaming videos and play them one after another.
My problem is that if I switch to next video after the first is finished, it will take time to load it and it is not playing them continuously (meaning starting to load the next before the first ends).

Is there any way to do that in ExoPlayer ? or any other player ?

Comment: Wanting to do this too. My current approach is trying to create a adaptation of the HLS implementation that uses separate files. It's quite complicated however :-/ not really getting anywhere.